# Group by type, but with 2 types as 1?

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know how to title this Q.

I got a table in my DB that's looking like this:

```
[id][name][type]
1-John-2
2-Jack-3
3-Liam-1
4-Kim-1
5-Michael-3
And many more
```

I would like to make a list where it's grouped by type,
but where type 1 and 2 is one group, like this:

```
[Type 1 and 2]
1 - John
3 - Liam
4 - Kim
[Type 3]
2 - Jack
```

Is it possible to group like that in MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use case

```
select *,
case when `type` =2 then 1 else `type` end new_type
from t
order by `type` ;
```

With aggregate fucntions

```
select count(*)
,case when `type` =2 then 1 else `type` end new_type
from t
group by new_type
```

[**`Demo`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58fea/5)